# TFS Build Error - initializing a build for build definition- wrong port

Tags: tfs, build

Have TFS installer on the server, unfortunately, we could not use the standard port 8080 used for a lot of communication.   In the TFS Admin Console, have changed the URLs to 8087 in the following areas...

- Application Tier using "Change URLs"
- Application Tier / Team Project Collections - changed URL
- Build Configuration - Build Services for collection
- In IIS,  changed port 8080 for "tfs" web app

When in the Team Foundation Server Explorer and start a build, I get the following error at the start, I believe it is attempting to retrieve the source.

```
    F215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Liberty-test\TFS-test: 
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
```

followed by last inner exception...

```
Exception Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 172.28.20.207:8080 (type SocketException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Notice the IP:8080 used when I suppose trying to retrieve the sources, e.g. 172.28.20.207:8080

It is still 8080, trying to determine where this IP/port comes from and how I can set it to 8087.

Comment: Do you mean you change the port to 8087 on IIS?Do you have any Reporting Services/Sharepoint sites?

Comment: Yes, was trying to change all ports to 8087, wasn't concerned about reporting or sharepoint at this time.  

After some discussion with IT, just ended up changing all back to 8080.  The reason they wanted it on a different port didn't warrant all the problems we were having as well as others not even seen yet :)

So, this is no longer an issue,  suppose will leave question in csae it may help others

Comment: It's possible to configure TFS to use a port rather than 8080. But this scenario is not tested and there could be potential issues. I was wondering your team didn't met the securing of Team Foundation Server with HTTPS and Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872(v=vs.120).aspx .I would suggest open the 8080 port and use it.